# Не понятная ошибка в коде

Tags: python-3.x

Ребята. Не пойму ошибку в пайчарме.Есть 4 строчки кода и я ожидаю увидеть список вот такой:
['яблоки', 'яблоко', 'яблоневый', 'яблочный']

Код:

```
import dawg_python

d = ['яблоко', 'яблоки', 'яблоневый', 'яблочный','вишня','малина','клубника']
d_dawg = dawg_python.DAWG(d)
print(d_dawg.keys('ябл'))
```

А в консоли вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/My_vocabulary/dawg.py", line 5, in <module>
    d_dawg = dawg_python.DAWG(d)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Покажите `def __init__(self, ???):` класса `DAWG` модуля `dawg_python.py`

Comment: Так в этом и странность, я и не использовал конструктор. Пытаюсь сделать пример как в документации как тут https://dawg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: по вашей ссылке я ничего не увидел об модуле `dawg_python` , а у вас он физически где-то есть. Посмотрите, что там в `def __init__(self, ???)`: класса `DAWG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `dawg_python` используйте просто `dawg`:

```
import dawg

d = ['яблоко', 'яблоки', 'яблоневый', 'яблочный','вишня','малина','клубника']
d_dawg = dawg.DAWG(d)
print(d_dawg.keys('ябл'))
```

[DAWG-Python](https://github.com/pytries/DAWG-Python) не умеет создать DAWGы - его цель совсем другая.